# C Program: Do-while loop to run program again not working properly

Tags: c, loops, do-while

My program is designed to sort records in a text file, but my main issue is getting the main function to ask the user if he would like to run the program again to read and write another file. My program right now, when the user enters 1 to run again, skips the first question to enter the program to read. Why is that? I appreciate the help! Here is my main function only: The program compiles only during the first run.

```
int main()
{
    int    fieldCount = 0;
    int    lineCount = 0;
    char file[STR_LEN];
    char   filepath[STR_LEN];
    char** fields = NULL;
    char** lines = NULL;
    int    recCount = 0;
    Person **sortedRecs = NULL;
    int x;

    do {
        printf("Enter path of the file to read: ");
        gets(filepath);
        printf("Enter path to copy to: ");
        gets(file);
        fields = readFieldsDynamic(filepath, &fieldCount);
        lines = readLinesDynamic(filepath, &lineCount);
        recCount = getPersons(fields, fieldCount, &sortedRecs);
        if (recCount && lines && sortedRecs && (recCount <= lineCount)) {
            writeRecsToFile(file, sortedRecs, recCount, lines, lineCount);
            printf("Sorted records are written in %s\n", file);
        }
        if (fields) {
            freePointerToChars(fields, fieldCount);
        }
        if (lines) {
            freePointerToChars(lines, lineCount);
        }
        if (sortedRecs) {
            freeRecs(sortedRecs, recCount);
        }
        printf("Enter 1 to run program again: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &x);
    } while (x == 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I posted the main function only as I don't thing the functions and structure have effect it properly looping

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer)

Comment: Thank you @user3121023! It solved my issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a while loop to "eat up" all the newlines left in `stdin` stream to prevent the next `getchar` to not block for real user input.

```
while ((ch=getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    ;
```

Also please don't use `gets` in your code. Try `fgets` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep a space before %c.

```
int main()
{
  char ch;
  do
  {
      something();
      printf("\nDo you want to continue?");
      scanf(" %c", &ch);
  }while(ch=='y');
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on your output looking something like:

```
Enter path of the file to read: /my/input/here/
Enter path to copy to: /blah/copy/here/
Enter 1 to run program again: 1
Enter path of the file to read: 
Enter path to copy to: help/I/cant/type/in/the/above/field
```

My understanding is your program is probably carrying over the newlines between loops.

I've had similar problems in C++, and placing `cin.get()` after an input fixed it. I'm not certain of the C equivalent.